# How to get kate to open a new file in the same workspace the file is called

Tags: 16.04, kate

I have started looking into using kate instead of gedit as my default text editor on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS machine and I like it, but there is one behaviour I have found a little infuriating: If I open a text file, and there is already an instance of kate running in a different workspace and on a different screen, the text file is opened in that instance and  there is no way to *then* separate the tab with the new file out into a new window.

Even if I manually start a new instance of kate in the new workspace, and then double click on a text file (in nautilus), it defaults to the original instance. This is proving quite irritating, as I cannot open text files on several work spaces at once. I really hope that I am just a blind fool missing some obvious.

Is there a way to tell kate to open files in the same workspace as they are "invoked"? To be clear, I do not want to open a new instance/window of kate every time I open a new file, just that the instance of kate in the same workspace is used.
Additionally, is there a way to separate out tabs from kate into new instances or transfer between instances?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS, with the Unity GUI, and kate seems to be version 15.12.3.

Thanks,
Don

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS is in it's last days of support unless you enable ESM](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) so consider *release-upgrading* asap.  You also mention Ubuntu 16 (closest being Ubuntu Core 16 which is a different product to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).  Ubuntu releases that are *yy* format are *snap* only, Ubuntu releases using *yy.mm* format are *deb* based but can use *snap* packages too.

Comment: Thank you, 16.04 LTS is indeed the correct version, I have edited the mention of Ubuntu 16.
Unfortunately, I am not in charge of upgrading the version, as it is an office environment. Our Admin plans on doing it in the not to distant future, though.